# parallelize a nested loop in python with multiprocessing

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing

I have a nested loop below which, given a long string `S` of length `n` and a query `Q` of length `m`, checks (naively) whether `Q` is a substring of `S` with `max_error` number of mismatches. Since each iteration of the outer loop is independent, it makes sense to parallelize it for speedup (right?).

For example, if `S=ATGGTC`, and `Q=TCCT`, and `max_err=2`, then `Q` is a match since substring `TGGT` in `S` has `<=2` mismatches with `Q`. But, if `max_err=1`, then `Q` is not a match in `S` because there is no substring of length 4 in `S` that matches with `P` with `<=1` mismatches.

```
def is_match(S,n,Q,m,max_err): # lengths; assume n>m
  for i in range(0,n-m):
    cnt = 0
    for k in range(m):
      if S[i+k]!=Q[k]: cnt += 1
      if cnt>max_err: break
    if cnt<=max_err: return i
  return -1
```

To parallelize it, I can make the inner loop a function like below. (I moved the `return -1` inside this function)

```
def inner_loop(S,Q,m,i):
    cnt = 0
    for k in range(m):
      if S[i+k]!=Q[k]: cnt += 1
      if cnt>max_err: break
    if cnt<=max_err: return i
    return -1
```

Now, I need to run the outer loop in parallel, collect the results, and check if there is a non-`-1` in the results. I am stuck here. Is the following code on the right way? How to collect the results?

```
def is_match_parallel(S,n,Q,m,max_err):
    inner_loop_1_par = inner_loop(S=S, Q=Q, m=m, i)
    result = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    ## the following line is not probably right
    result = pool.map(inner_loop_1_par, range(n-m))
    for i in range(n-m):
        if result[i]!=-1: return i
    return -1
```

Also, as soon as any of the processes above returns a non-`-1` value, we are done, and we don't need to wait for the rest of them. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What is max_err? Can you provide an input and expected output? Why not use more pythonic approaches?

Comment: @atru I added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea worked in a modified form. Namely, `pool.map()` had to be substituted with a bit more complex approach since your function requires more parameters than just an iterable parameter. Also, using your functions relies on returned values and that also needs special treatment in multiprocessing.

The following solution uses separately called instances of `Process` object and a shared variable that indicates whether there was a match for given conditions:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def inner_loop(flag,S,Q,m,i,max_err):
    cnt = 0
    if flag.value == -1:
        for k in range(m):
            if S[i+k]!=Q[k]:
                cnt += 1
            if cnt>max_err:
                break
        if cnt<=max_err:
            flag.value = 1

def is_match_parallel(S,n,Q,m,max_err):
    flag = Value('i', -1)
    processes = []
    for i in range(0,n-m):
        p = Process(target=inner_loop, args=(flag,S,Q,m,i,max_err,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in processes: p.join()
    return flag
```

This solution was written in Python 2.7 but it should be straightforward to implement it in Python 3.X.

The `is_match_parallel` initializes a shared variable `flag` using a special multiprocessing object `Value`. That object is by default supposed to be protected from multiple threads accessing it at the same time so that part of the program is skipped. `flag` is an integer (`"i"`) indicator of weather `Q` is a substring of `S`. It is initialized to -1 because the remaining multiprocessed `inner_loop` will change it to 1 only if a match was found.

A separate process is started for each `i` in the `n-m` range. Note that for large ranges you may want to benchmark this and make sure that starting many processes doesn't slow things down. In that case you would need to split the loop into larger chunks which should not be a problem.

`p = Process(target=inner_loop, args=(flag,S,Q,m,i,max_err,))` sets the target function to `inner_loop` with arguments `args`, including the shared variable `flag`. After that the process is started. After the loop, `for p in processes: p.join()` causes the program to wait on that line until all process have finished processing `inner_loop`.

If a match is found, the process processing the `inner_loop` will set `flag` to 1 with `flag.value = 1`. If not, `flag` value will remain -1 signifying no matches where found. When all processes are done, `is_match_parallel` returns current `flag` as a `Value` object (that can be changed by returning only `flag.value`).

In this current version of `inner_loop` all processes call the `inner_loop` but a process will enter the main body of the function - with the loop - only if the `flag` is still -1. This way, once the `flag` becomes 1, processes will only race through the function and skip the time consuming part.

Example usages for your inputs are:

```
s = 'ATGGTC'
q = 'TCCT'

res = is_match_parallel(s, len(s), q, len(q), 2)
print res.value

res = is_match_parallel(s, len(s), q, len(q), 1)
print res.value
```

Which return 1 and -1 respectively.

Comment: Thank you! So here we will wait until all processes are done, right? If yes, is there any way to stop other processes as soon as one of them finds a match?

Comment: Yes, we're waiting :) I'll think about it, there surely is one. That would actually make sense - I'm not sure how much it would speed things up the way it is now. Maybe for really long strings - is this for some DNA processing or are the letters a coincidence?

Comment: Done, now the processes will enter the loop in `inner_loop` only if the match is not found yet. Racing through the function without looping should not really be time consuming. Let me know how this is working. I tested it with a bit larger string to invoke more processes and it worked well, but I haven't timed it.